# Wallet Transfer Method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder, wallet

I'm taking a beginning Java class and am working the Wallet lab.

I need to transfer the wallet contents of one wallet(donor wallet) to the end of another(receiver wallet).

I believe a have my constructors set up correctly.

```
    import.java.util.Arrays;

    public class Wallet
    {
       private static final int MAX = 10;  //Max possible # of banknotes in a wallet

   // instance variables       
       private int contents[]; //array of banknotes
       private int count; //number of banknotes stored in contents[]

   /**
    * Default constructor for objects of class Wallet
    */
   public Wallet()
   {
        // initialize instance variables
        contents = new int[MAX];
        count = 0;       
   }

   /**
    * Overloaded constructor for objects of class Wallet
    */
   public Wallet(int a[])
   {
       contents = new int[MAX]; 

       for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
       {
            contents=a;
            if (contents[i] > 0) 
                count++;
       }
   }
```

but need help verifying if the below add() method I wrote is correct:

```
public void add(int banknote)//Not sure if this is right
   {  
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for (int i = 0; i<contents.length; i++)
                sb.append(contents[i] + ", ");

       sb.append(banknote);

       count++;

   }
```

or should this be:

```
 contents[count] = banknote;
  count++;
```

I also need to transfer the contents of a donor wallet to a receiver wallet, emptying the donor wallet and adding to the receiver, i wrote the below code, but it seems off and is not working correctly:

```
 public void transfer(Wallet donor)
   {

      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            add(donor.contents[i]);
            count++;
        }
      donor.count=0;
   }
```

any guidance on where i could be getting this wrong, been at this for hours now..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should resolve some of the issues:

```
public Wallet(int a[]) {
  contents = new int[MAX];
  count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > 0)
      contents[count++] = a[i];  
      // only increase your content position for actual notes
  }

public void add(int banknote) {
  contents[count++] = banknote;  
  /* this version makes a lot more sense
   * as you actually mutate your instance */
}

public void transfer(Wallet donor) {
  for(int i = 0; i < donor.count; i++) // gotta use donor.count here
    add(donor.contents[i]);
  donor.count=0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** I recommend that you use a List of Integer, as this would simplify your code much more. My code in this answer has been adapted to this.

First of all, you do not need to keep track of how many 'bank notes' are in the array in a separate variable: just call `contents.length`, which will return how many 'bank notes' there are in the Wallet.

Then, to add a bank note to the wallet, I would make your 'add' function return a boolean: true if the bill was added, and false if the wallet didn't contain enough space. To do so, you could do something such as:

```
static int MAX = 10;
static List<Integer> contents = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String... args){
    add(5);
    add(10);

    transfer(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 2, 4));

    for(int note: contents){
        System.out.println(note);
    }
}

public static boolean add(int note){
    if(contents.size() >= MAX)
        return false; // The wallet is full, therefore we cannot add anything.

    contents.add(note);
    return true;
}
```

To transfer money, you would then simply do:

```
public static void transfer(List<Integer> donor){ // You would change 'int[]' to Wallet, and the code below according to this change
    for(int i = 0; i < donor.size(); i++) // Going through all the values of the donor's wallet
        if(!add(donor.get(i))) // If there is no space left, we must stop the transfer
            return;
}
```

When launching this class, your console should print:

```
5
10
1
5
2
4
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: `contents[contents.length] = note;` will always throw an index error!

Comment: Indeed. I would recommend that he uses list then, this would simplify his life much more.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I edited the code accordingly, showing how this will drastically reduce the amount of work he has to do. However, your answer is still here if he wants to persist with the array.

Comment: Still several issues with that. `donor` should be a `Wallet` instance. This looks very much like a training exercise tht is supposed to deal with emptying the donor Wallet while filling the receiver. Also, the use of arrays appears to be didactly induced ;)

Comment: Yeah. I assumed that he would be able to put the code correctly in his different classes.